# How do I get ELMAH to log full exception details?

Tags: elmah.mvc

When my server encounters an error ELMAH successfully creates a log of the error including the URL & post data etc but the details of the exception itself are not in the xml log file. How do I change this?

Comment: don't you have in the "error" tag the "detail" attribute?

Comment: Doh, yes. I really didn't expect to see so much detail in an attribute so I didn't scroll across to check  for it. Add this as an answer and I will accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "detail" attribute of the "error" tag contains the details of the exception.